# PHP array to objective-c NSArray (Xcode)

Tags: php, objective-c, arrays

Is it possible to transform an array in PHP into an NSArray?

PHP code:

```
<?php
$DB_HostName = "XXXXX";
$DB_Name = "XXXXX";
$DB_User = "XXXXX";
$DB_Pass = "XXXXX";
$DB_Table = "Name";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Name");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

$Name = $row['name'];
$LastName = $row['lastname'];

echo "$Name $LastName";
echo "<br />";

}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Can I make "$Name" and "$LastName" to Foundation-styled NSArrays without using JSON?

Comment: What do you mean xcode array? Objective-c array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017575/how-to-parse-arrays-in-array-php-json-xcode?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

First of all xcode is an IDE not a language ;) Your language of choice is objective-c.

What you have to do is do a request to the php page (if you are going to use this on a real app and not for an exercise, you'll have to put the page somewhere publicly) and get the data for processing.

Since you don't want this to be json, you can have easy options and hard options on how to get the data into an array.

One way is using delimiters. For example your output could be:

```
Michael Westen##Fiona Glenanne##Sam Axe
```

You can get that easily using the following:

```
NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:nil error:nil];
myArray = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"];
```

Where `url` is the url of the page you want to get the data and `myArray` your `NSArray`.

Comment: Also remember that you have to output them in UTF-8, or else funky characters will come out.